# не работает функция из-за display:none

Tags: html, jquery

```js
$('.chat').scrollTop(100000); // эта функция не выполняется из-за display:none, если убрать это свойство то она заработает.
 $('#chat-click').click(function() {
   $('.chat').toggle();
 });
```

```css
.chat {
  display:none;
  height:100px;
  overflow-y:scroll;
  width:300px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="chat">
  <li>message</li>
  <li>message</li>
  <li>message</li>
  <li>message</li>
  <li>message</li>
  <li>message</li>
  <li>message</li>
  <li>message</li>
  <li>message</li>
  <li>message</li>
  <li>message</li>
  <li>message</li>
</div>

<button id="chat-click">OPEN/CLOSE</button>
```

Не выполняется функция scrolltop, из-за того что изначально селектору `chat` присвоен параметр `display:none`, если его убрать все заработает. Как это обойти?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/qa5s6vrm/

Comment: временное решение. https://jsfiddle.net/qa5s6vrm/2/

Comment: А "временное" решение чем не устраивает?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
 $('#chat-click').click(function() {
   $('.chat').toggle();
   $('.chat').scrollTop(100000); 
 });
```

```css
.chat {
  display:none;
  height:100px;
  overflow-y:scroll;
  width:300px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="chat">
  <li>message</li>
  <li>message</li>
  <li>message</li>
  <li>message</li>
  <li>message</li>
  <li>message</li>
  <li>message</li>
  <li>message</li>
  <li>message</li>
  <li>message</li>
  <li>message</li>
  <li>message</li>
</div>

<button id="chat-click">OPEN/CLOSE</button>
```

Пришел к такому решению. Чтобы при каждом нажатии на кнопку - выполнялась функция.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема действительно в `display:none`, так как нельзя прокрутить элемент, если у него нет прокрутки.

Обойти можно несколькими путями:

1. прокручивать в обработчике клика, когда элемент стал видимым
2. сделать элемент видимым, прокрутить, скрыть элемент
   Например:

   ```js
   $('.chat').show().scrollTop(100000).hide(); // эта функция не выполняется из-за display:none, если убрать это свойство то она заработает.
   $('#chat-click').click(function() {
     $('.chat').toggle();
   });
   ```

   ```css
   .chat {
     display: none;
     height: 100px;
     overflow-y: scroll;
     width: 300px
   }
   ```

   ```html
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.js"></script>
   <div class="chat">
     <li>message</li>
     <li>message</li>
     <li>message</li>
     <li>message</li>
     <li>message</li>
     <li>message</li>
     <li>message</li>
     <li>message</li>
     <li>message</li>
     <li>message</li>
     <li>message</li>
     <li>message</li>
   </div>

   <button id="chat-click">OPEN/CLOSE</button>
   ```
3. убрать из класса display:none, прокрутить элемент и скрыть его

   ```js
   $('.chat').scrollTop(100000).hide(); // эта функция не выполняется из-за display:none, если убрать это свойство то она заработает.
   $('#chat-click').click(function() {
     $('.chat').toggle();
   });
   ```

   ```css
   .chat {
     height: 100px;
     overflow-y: scroll;
     width: 300px
   }
   ```

   ```html
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.js"></script>
   <div class="chat">
     <li>message</li>
     <li>message</li>
     <li>message</li>
     <li>message</li>
     <li>message</li>
     <li>message</li>
     <li>message</li>
     <li>message</li>
     <li>message</li>
     <li>message</li>
     <li>message</li>
     <li>message</li>
   </div>

   <button id="chat-click">OPEN/CLOSE</button>
   ```